# How to get cell value in the formula bar in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel data sheet and this sheet has a cell that the visible value and the value in the formula bar are different.

I used `Cell.Value` but it returns the visible value. I want to get the value in the bar.

**Image to understand question:**

[image]

I mean the visible value is MMK333098333101 and the bar value is MMK333098.

So how can I get the bar value in VBA Excel?

Comment: You can also get the same in VBA using `Rng.Text`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bar value is both. If you drag the bar down you will see both values. It is separated by a line insert. You can't see the second line because you are only showing one line in the formula bar.

[image]

If you want the first part then you will need to use LEFT and Find to find the carriage return and take all the values before it.

```
=LEFT(A1,FIND(CHAR(10),A1)-1)
```

[image]

Comment: Oh! That's funny. I just found out that. I was wondering how those values can be different already. Thanks for the answer @Scott Craner.